# How can I get data from MySQL for each user

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, session

I need help. I crated a MySQL database and I connected database with login and registration form. All it´s working. I tried to create page that show all data about user from database. I created tried this code:

```
<p>Username: <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p>
<p>Email: <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></p>
<p>Create profile date and time: <?php echo $_SESSION['create_datetime']; ?></p>
```

But that showed me only username.
I created this from [this](https://www.speedysense.com/create-registration-login-system-php-mysql/) page.
Can you help me with this? Very much thanks for response!

Comment: In [that](https://speedysense.com/create-registration-login-system-php-mysql/) page, he never assigns `email` and `create_datetime` to `$_SESSION`. So once you get data from `db`  you need to assign those values to `$_SESSION`

Comment: Just because the veneer of a web site look new and sexy does not make the tutorials on it any good. This one is NOT GOOD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside login.php page you need to assign email and create_datetime to $_SESSION. It should be like

```
if ($rows == 1) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row["username"];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row["email"];
            $_SESSION['create_datetime'] = $row["create_datetime"];
        }
        // Redirect to user dashboard page
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
    }
```